# how to call a string as a variable in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line-interface, sh

I have a problem that I will not know the name of the variable and the name of the variable will be stored in an array that I have,

the problem here how can I call it, I tried some in the cli to see:

```
$ hello=sup
$ hi=hello
$ echo $`echo $hi`
$hello
```

as you see it prints "$hello" instead of "sup" that I want

Comment: Some shells support `echo ${!hi}`, all will work with `eval echo \$$hi`

Comment: Are you using `bash` or POSIX shell?

Comment: `eval`, as always, is not safe with untrusted input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dereference a variable you have to use the $ so the second assignment isn't working in your code sample.

```
>hello=sup
>hi=$hello
>echo $hi
sup
```

See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html for more info on indirect variable references.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following in bash:

```
echo ${!hi}
```

or eval in other shells

```
eval "echo \$$hi"
```